# Why does GetMapping with @RestController annotation not show the html page, but everything works with @Controller?

Tags: spring-mvc

I have two html pages:

**greeting.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Getting Started: Handling Form Submission</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<h1>Form</h1>
<form action="#" th:action="@{/greeting}" th:object="${greeting}" method="post">
    <p>Id: <input type="text" th:field="*{ch}" /></p>
    <p>Message: <input type="number" th:field="*{count}" /></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**result.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
  <title>Getting Started: Handling Form Submission</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<h1>Result</h1>
<p th:text="'symbol: ' + ${greeting.ch}" />
<p th:text="'count: ' + ${greeting.count}" />
<a href="/greeting">Submit another message</a>
</body>
</html>
```

And a simple controller:

```
package com.example.secMVC.Controller;

import com.example.secMVC.Entity.CharacteristicsEntity;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@Controller
public class UserController {

    @GetMapping("/greeting")
    public String greetingForm(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("greeting",new CharacteristicsEntity());
        return "greeting";
    }

    @PostMapping("/greeting")
    public String greetingSubmit(@ModelAttribute CharacteristicsEntity charEntity,Model model){
        model.addAttribute("greeting",charEntity);
        return "result";
    }
}
```

And now if I run the program with the `@Controller` annotation, it shows what is needed, i.e. a page with input fields and 2 buttons.But if you change it to `@RestContoller`, then just a page with the text **"greeting"** is shown.

I'm a beginner and apparently I don't understand something, but I saw that they wrote that these should be equivalent annotations in theory.I would be glad to help figure out this issue.

Entity just in case:

```
package com.example.secMVC.Entity;

public class CharacteristicsEntity {
    private String ch;
    private Integer count;

    public String getCh() {
        return ch;
    }

    public void setCh(String ch) {
        this.ch = ch;
    }

    public Integer getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(Integer count) {
        this.count = count;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well `@RestContoller` annotation is used when someone creates a RESTful webservices (REST APIs). `@RestContoller` actually takes care of all the boilerplate code when you creating a RESTful webservice.

Theoretically `@Controller` and `@RestContoller` is not equal. But yet you can use both of these annotation if you are creating RESTful webservices in following combination.

```
@RestContoller
public class ClassName{}
```

or

```
@Controller
@ResponseBody
public class ClassName{}
```

But when you use template engine like `Thymeleaf`, you better use `@Controller` rather than `@RestContoller`.

*For more info - [Here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-controller-vs-restcontroller)*